# Red Square Appears when Writing Asterisk

Tags: comment

I am creating a new variable "t", and when I go to define it and then comment on what it represents, I type " t = 2 (*  " and immediately after I type the asterisk, a red square appears next to t. This also happened when I tried to do a simple multiplication of 2 * 3, a red square appeared after I typed the asterisk. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot repeat this behavior (MMa 12.0, Win10).

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard probably has the asterisk in the "+" key. However, 'Shift'+'+' is also a Mathematica shortcut for a new item cell, thus the red square.

Use the asterisk from the extended numerical keyboard (if you have it), or insert comments with the convenient shortcut 'Alt'+'/'